# Remove special characters from Japanese language string using regular expression in C#

Tags: .net

I have a string like this (string inputstring = "xyz's &#123456 , 外部広告掲載費用 how are you?'"). I want to remove the special characters from this string using regular expression in C#. i need output like this (xyzs 123456  外部広告掲載費用 how are you), Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
string finalstring = Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]", "");
```

Here the Unicode categories: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx

```
\p{L} are Letters
\p{N} are Numbers
\s are space characters
```

I negate everything, and so remove the characters that aren't part of all the three categories.

Note that technically I went overboard... that regex will "accept" and not "remove" other scripts, so if you encounter a mixed english-chinese-japanese-arab string, the chinese and arab characters will be left in place. While it is easy to remove "arab" characters, removing "chinese" characters can be complex, because there is the [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs)...

You could start with something like:

```
string finalstring = Regex.Replace(inputstring, @"[^\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}\p{IsHiragana}\p{IsKatakana}\p{IsCJKUnifiedIdeographs}\s]", "");
```

and then see if you need to add other CJK blocks... (same page, "Supported Named Block" section). This will remove "arab" (and other scripts), but clearly won't do anything for the CJK "problem".

Answer (score 0):

You could create a char-array of banned characters and use two for-loops like this:

```
string inputstring =  "xyz's &#123456 , 外部広告掲載費用 how are you?'";
string outputstring = "";
char[] bannedCharacters = new char[]{'\'', '&', '#', ',', '?'};
bool isOk;

for(int i = 0; i < inputstring.Length; i++){
    isOk = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < bannedCharacters.Length; j++){
        if(inputString[i] == bannedCharacters[j]){
            isOk = false;
        }
    }
    if(isOk){
        outputstring += inputstring[i];
    }
}
```